# How do I add a method to an object instance with a variable from the current scope (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, reflection

This is hard to explain as a question but here is a code fragment:

```
n = "Bob"
class A
end
def A.greet
  puts "Hello #{n}"
end
A.greet
```

This piece of code does not work because n is only evaluated inside A.greet when it is called, rather than when I add the method.

Is there a way to pass the value of a local variable into A.greet?

What about if n was a function?

Comment: why not just pass it in as a parameter:  A.greet(n) for example?

Comment: Because the piece of code calling greet does not know the value of n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use metaprogramming, specifically the `define_singleton_method` method.  This allows you to use a block to define the method and so captures the current variables.

```
n = "Bob"

class A
end

A.define_singleton_method(:greet) do
  puts "Hello #{n}"
end

A.greet
```

Comment: This works, though I am still a bit unhappy. If I put this code fragment in a method (eg def f(obj) n="Bob"; obj.define_... end), I can only access n if it is defined in that method, not if it is an instance var or a global (outside method) var. Also, being able to reference both the method's environment (static scoping) and the object A's environment (dynamic scoping) leaves me traumatized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global ($n = "Bob")...

Comment: You don't want to use globals that lightly.

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer **Nemo157**'s way you can also do this:

```
n = "Bob"

class A
end

#Class.instance_eval "method"
A.instance_eval "def greet; puts 'Hello #{n}' end"

#eval Class.method
eval "def A.greet2; puts 'Hi #{n}' end"

A.greet
A.greet2
```

Comment: That is right Sony, basically you get `puts 'Hello Bob'` inside the method.